# How to 'extend' a react functional component in typescript?

Tags: typescript

My google-fu is failing because of another question with similar wording.

I have access to some component, `<TsCode />`, and I want to create a wrapper for this, that forwards everything directly to the underlying component, but provide a value for one prop. So I create

```
const PrettyTsCode: ??? = (props) => {
   return <TsCode pretty={true} {...props} />
}
```

In any other language, I would expect something like `const PrettyTsCode: TsCode` or perhaps `const PrettyTsCode: typeof TsCode`, but neither seem to work.

I can look at the type information of `TsCode`, but that wouldn't be resilient to change, as it might change in the future.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: If `TsCode` is a functional component, then you could probably use `(props: Omit<Parameters<TsCode>[0], "pretty">) => ReturnType<TsCode>`.

Comment: A variation on that worked; thanks :)